# Smart pointer(unique_ptr) custom deleter error C2027 & C2338

Tags: c++, sdl, smart-pointers, sdl-2

I try to use smart pointers with SDL2 and I need a custom deleter. I use this code and get errors C2027 (using the undefined type SDL_Texture) & C2338 (can't delete an incomplete type)

```
ftexture = std::make_unique<SDL_Texture>(TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, fontData.c_str(), fontColor),
        [=](SDL_Texture* texture) {SDL_DestroyTexture(texture); });
```

This variable in my class looks like this:

```
std::unique_ptr <SDL_Texture> ftexture = nullptr;
```

Comment: Did you include the header that defines the type? [mcve] please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `TTF_RenderText_Solid()` returns an `SDL_Surface*`, not an `SDL_Texture*`. `SDL_Surface` does not derive from `SDL_Texture`.

Second, you can't specify a custom deleter with `std::make_unique()`. The 1st template argument is used as the `T` type of the resulting `std::unique_ptr`, and the remaining template arguments are used for the input parameters, which are all passed to `T`'s constructor. In your example, `T` is `SDL_Texture`, and there is no constructor of `SDL_Texture` that takes an `SDL_Surface*` and a lambda as input.

To use a custom deleter, you need to specify the deleter's type as a template argument of `std::unique_ptr`, which `std::make_unique()` does not allow you to do, so you have to use `std::unique_ptr` directly.

The deleter should be a separate type rather than a lambda:

```cpp
struct SDL_Surface_Deleter
{
    void operator()(SDL_Surface* surface) {
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    } 
};

using SDL_Surface_ptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SDL_Surface_Deleter>;
```

```cpp
SDL_Surface_ptr fsurface;

...

fsurface = SDL_Surface_ptr(
    TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, fontData.c_str(), fontColor)
);
```

But if you really want to use a lambda, you can do this instead:

```cpp
using SDL_Surface_Deleter = void (*)(SDL_Surface*);
using SDL_Surface_ptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SDL_Surface_Deleter>;
```

```cpp
SDL_Surface_ptr fsurface;

...

fsurface = SDL_Surface_ptr(
    TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, fontData.c_str(), fontColor),
    [](SDL_Surface* surface) { SDL_FreeSurface(surface); }
);
```

Or, you can just use `SDL_FreeSurface()` directly as the actual deleter:

```cpp
using SDL_Surface_ptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, decltype(&SDL_FreeSurface)>;
```

```cpp
SDL_Surface_ptr fsurface;

...

fsurface = SDL_Surface_ptr(
    TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, fontData.c_str(), fontColor),
    &SDL_FreeSurface
);
```